# In Artemis Fowl: the Last Guardian, how many of these are there?

Tags: artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-last-guardian

In *Artemis Fowl: the Last Guardian*, the final book of the *Artemis Fowl* series, there are a bunch of

> Opal Koboi's.

I couldn't keep track of them all.

As of the events of *The Last Guardian*, how many

> Opal Koboi's (including Nopal)

are there?  How many versions have there been?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 Opal Koboi's and one Opal clone. There is Opal from the past and Opal from the present, and they work together. That's what I remember from the Last Guardian.

Comment: Do you have any quote to support your answer?; it would be a great addition.

Answer (score 5):

In The Last Guardian, the only Opal whose **viewpoint** is shown is the **future/present** one (basically, the one locked up in Atlantis, not the one who was brought into the future 2 books back).

> Opportunity had presented itself to Opal when her younger self had made telepathic contact.
>
> One morning Opal had been deep in a cleansing coma and *- ping! -* suddenly there was a voice in her head calling her sister and asking for help. It had occurred to her briefly that she could in fact be insane but, little by little, the information filtered through. *A younger Opal had followed Artemis Fowl back from the past.*

This flashback is only recalled after the younger Opal is killed, of course.

Nopal is really only important in the ending, although she is shown in the beginning as well, typical of Colfer's style of showing all of Artemis' cards before the battle has begun. Following is an excerpt from the part after Artemis is done with his final session with Argon:

> He placed his hand on the glass, tapping his fingers in sequence slowly, building up a rhythm. “It is an exercise developed by Cuba’s Dr. Parnassus. He uses it to generate a response from infants, even chimpanzees.”
>
> Artemis continued to tap, and slowly Nopal responded, raising her hand laboriously to Artemis’s, slapping the glass clumsily in an attempt to copy his rhythm.

**Nopal** is the clone, complete with limited brain activity, and is slowly dying, as clones (in this universe) are wont to do.

> Cloning was a banned science both for religious reasons and the more obvious fact that, without a life force or soul to power their systems, clones were doomed to a short life of negligent brain activity and organ failure. This particular clone had lived out most of its days in an incubator, struggling for each breath since it had been removed from the chrysalis in which it had been grown.

Anyhoo, Nopal is Artemis' second request of Foaly near the end of the book. The tactic used to defeat Koboi once and for all in the series climax is literally told to us, for those who look for it. I won't mention it here, as it would nullify any tension anybody who likes/reads this series would ever have (if reading it for the first time).

If by "As of The Last Guardian", you mean "after", then

> there are none. They're all dead.